# AngularJS AJAX Replace HTML

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I want to make an AJAX request to my server (GET) and get a rendered view back from Laravel, I then want to take that HTML and stick it in a div with an id of 'foo', how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe ng-bind-html https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml will do the trick

in html:

```
<div ng-bind-html="myScopeVariablewithHTML"></div>
```

in javascript:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.myScopeVariablewithHTML = doSomethingWithResponse(response);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {

  });
```